# PDU to text conversion in Java

Tags: java, sms, pdu

i need help in converting sms in PDU mode to text mode in Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Android PDUParser,

http://www.androidjavadoc.com/m5-rc15/com/google/android/mms/pdu/package-tree.html

Comment: I assume http://alvinalexander.com/java/jwarehouse/android/core/java/com/google/android/mms/pdu/PduParser.java.shtml is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can also use GSM_DecodePDUFrame from [libGammu](http://wammu.eu/libgammu) through JNI.